# Unable to debug a Windows 8.1 store apps from Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-store

When I try to debug even a simple template project from Windows App store 8.1 in VS2013. Ii can't have the application. I have no proble with ressources in my computer. It still giving me the text in the output `Registration of the application to run from the disposal ...`. And no launch for the apps.

Should I repair my VS2013? Where am I wrong?

### EDIT

I repaired but it doesn't launch the windows store apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came accross this bug. I don't what was the proble but I spent like one day reapairing VS 2013 but it didn't helped me.
The solution was to **REPAIR** my Windows 8.1 which took like less than 10 minutes. An advice from my colleague